# How can I make a button appear on scroll just using 'plain' html, CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, scroll

I've tried to accomplish this, (since I am a noob at coding...) with a concept I found online... it didn't work out very well, and offline the scroll padding and "Sign In' button appears for a second than disappears...

To view web:

[Click Here](https://gorilloidif.htmlpasta.com/)

if someone can please send me a simple code including: Html, (Css,) JavaScript, (no Jquery) of how to accomplish the same idea (of the button) on that site...

Thank You!

Comment: Hi Eli, do you have a JSFiddle to share with us?

Comment: @Souki1990 Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rk9Lc0eo/ I didn't separate the CSS and JavaScript (I was too lazy to)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to listen for window scroll events and check to see if the main button is visible. You can do this by checking it's position inside the window using `Element.getBoundingClientRect();`

The `bottom` property tells you how many pixels the bottom of the element is from the top of the screen. If the number is below zero, it means the bottom of the element is off the top of the screen.

At that point, just toggle the hidden button into view. In my demo, I did this by adding a CSS class to that button.

If the user scrolls up and the main button is visible again, you can hide the side button by removing the class you previously added to it.

[JS Fiddle Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1pvc08u9/)

Comment: Thanks! There's still a problem, when you click the "sign in" button the sign in button in the side appears... Any way to fix that?

Comment: and when the "sign in" pops in is it possible to add a 'bounce' affect (it goes all the way than 'bounces'  a bit like the one I made before)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the code and try to fix it yourself. You're asking me to do your work. You need to learn it for yourself. For the bounce effect, look at CSS animations via keyframes.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry for asking for too much...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using scroll event with getBoundingClientRect may decrease performance
You can use intersection observer for checking an element enter in viewport
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver